# Using a switch case can you put expressions in the case?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it valid to put expressions in a case statement? I have this switch case statement.

```
var switchValue:String = StatusUpdateErrorEvent.UPDATE_ERROR;

switch (switchValue) {

    case caseValue: { // it's implied here that (switchValue==caseValue)

    }
    case StatusUpdateErrorEvent.UPDATE_ERROR: {

    }
    case event is StatusUpdateErrorEvent && StatusUpdateErrorEvent.UPDATE_ERROR: {

    }
    // is this what I should do if I add my own expression?
    case event is StatusUpdateErrorEvent && StatusUpdateErrorEvent.UPDATE_ERROR==type: {

    }
}
```

It doesn't throw any errors when I add an expression is the switchValue==caseValue expression thrown out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
switch (switchValue) {
        case caseValue:
            //1
            break;
        case StatusUpdateErrorEvent.UPDATE_ERROR:
            //2
            break;
        case event is StatusUpdateErrorEvent && StatusUpdateErrorEvent.UPDATE_ERROR:
            //3
            break;
        case event is StatusUpdateErrorEvent && StatusUpdateErrorEvent.UPDATE_ERROR == type:
            //4
            break;
    }
```

You need to use "break;" after every case. If not, all other breaks **after** will be executed. It can e also "return;" if you just want to exit function after break.

Other thing is that you use "case" in a very weird way, just like they are if's. Don't put boolean comparison there like that. It's place for values.

Comment: OK. It was moving to the next case. I did not have breaks in there. So in case 3 I have a boolean `StatusUpdateErrorEvent.UPDATE_ERROR` that will always return true because it is not null. But in case 4 correct I check two conditions. IIUC case 4 is correct but case 3 is not?

Comment: So if I do not put break then the next case after the first matching case is also run? Let's say I match case 1 but do not put a break in it. Does case 2 run because case 1 ran?

Comment: Yes. Without break you will run 2 switch and the rest.
Your input in switch is String value I guess. In 3 and 4 for you have Boolean values so this don't make sense.